# Comparison of queryset and list using template tags in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a list and a queryset that always consists of the same number of objects.

```
query = object1, object2, object3

list = ['true', 'false', 'true']
```

I would like to always show my user object when the in list is true.

In my case, the user should see `object1` and `object3` from query (because the first and last item on the list is true).

I tried it:

```
{% for object in query %} <!-- Show all objects in query -->
  {% if list.forloop.counter == 'true' %} <!-- get element from list and check if true -->
    {{ object.name }} <-- Show my object name from query if the equation is true -->
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But mine {{ forloop.counter }} does not work properly in markup. How can I get the expected result?

Comment: This kind of logic needs to go in the view (or use Jinja templates).

Comment: you can filter your queryset in views bases on True and False before rendering it using a template engine.